# Unable to edit CQWP within publishing site

Tags: content-query-web-part, edit

When I add a Content Query to any page within a 2010 publishing site collection, either via checked-out page edit (Wiki or BWP page) or via SPD, I receive an error when I attempt to edit the webpart.

The correlation error contains the following;

> ConsoleUtilies.GetContextualControlMode had no currentPage so the
>   current SPWebPartManager mode cannot be retrieved.
>
> System.ArgumentNullException: Key cannot be null.  Parameter name: key
>   at System.Collections.Hashtable.ContainsKey(Object key)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ContentByQueryWebPart.addFieldIntoHashTable(Hashtable
>   table, SPField field)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ContentByQueryWebPart.createAllFieldsForDataViewMapping()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ContentByQueryWebPart.get_AllFieldsForDataViewMapping()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ContentByQueryToolPart.getDisplayedDataViewMapping(SPWeb
>   web, String input)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ContentByQueryToolPart.populateFieldsToDisplayControlGroup(Boolean
>   clearInvalidMappings)

Comment: check this one https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9384948e-59a9-4d91-aa0f-7e12deb2de8f/clicking-on-edit-web-part-of-content-query-its-giving-error-on-page?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious

Comment: THank you Waqas. I've previously reviewed the linked TechNet discussion. It appears to be of a similar nature, but unfortunately it doesn't offer a proposed solution.